# how to count second col if first col value is null and avoid duplicate count

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm making sales statistic report to calculate scanned documents station wise using below Query:

```
SELECT
 RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(11),DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,InvoiceDate),0),13),LEN 
 (CONVERT(varchar(11),DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,InvoiceDate),0),13))-3) 
 [Month], COUNT(GDNNo)TotalInvoices,(COUNT(InvoiceAttachment)+ 
 COUNT(GDNAttachmentStatus))ScannedInvoices,
 (COUNT(GDNNo)-(COUNT(InvoiceAttachment)+COUNT(GDNAttachmentStatus)))[Remaining],
 round(cast((Count(InvoiceAttachment)+COUNT(GDNAttachmentStatus))as 
 float)/COUNT(GDNNo)*100 ,3)[Completion]

 FROM SaleDocuments WHERE InvoiceDate between '2020/05/03' and '2020/06/23'
 GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, InvoiceDate), 0), StationId order by 
 [Month] desc
```

[image]

but i want if **InvoiceAttachmentStatus** is `null` then `count` **GDNAttachmentStatus**. The method which I'm following counts duplicate data in case of **InvoiceAttachmentStatus, GDNAttachmentStatus** both values present.
How to count single value only if one column is `null`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that i had tried yesterdays was

```sql
Select COUNT(GDNNo)TotalInvoices,count(Count_Scanned)ScannedInvoices,
(COUNT(GDNNo)-count(Count_Scanned))[Remaining],
round(cast(count(Count_Scanned)as float)/COUNT(GDNNo)*100 ,3)[Completion]
from
( 
  select InvoiceDate,InvoiceAttachment,InvoiceAttachmentStatus,StationId,SaleOrderAttachment,GDNNo,GDNAttachmentStatus,
    case when InvoiceAttachment is not null or SaleOrderAttachment is not null then 1 
    when InvoiceAttachment is not null and SaleOrderAttachment is not null then 1 
    END AS Count_Scanned
    from SaleDocuments 
) sub_query
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE statement to determine if either column or both columns are `NOT NULL`. Based on the CASE condition, you set a pseudo column to 1 or 0 (1 for any of the columns being `NOT NULL` or 0 for all columns beings `NULL`). You can then group by your required columns and aggregate the pseudo column to count the number of rows where at least one of the columns is `NOT NULL.`

You can see a mock example of [this here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7f37a837aae68882d617d08cb5e3941a).

```sql
SELECT StationId,  SUM(Value)
    FROM
    (
    SELECT StationId,
      CASE
        WHEN Col1 IS NOT NULL OR Col2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END AS Value
    FROM Records
    ) inner_query
GROUP BY StationId
```

Comment: why we are summing values ? can't we use count()?

Comment: @Osama, replace 0 with null (or remove the else clause since it is the default), you can then count instead of sum

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE to match:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Col1 IS NULL AND Col2 IS NULL THEN 1 END) as CASE1
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Col1 IS NULL AND Col2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) as CASE2
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Col1 IS NOT NULL AND Col2 IS NULL THEN 1 END) as CASE3
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Col1 IS NOT NULL AND Col2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) as CASE4
FROM ...
```

As long as your CASE expressions are mutually exclusive, rows are counted just once. If the predicate in CASE evaluates to FALSE, NULL is returned, i.e. is not counted.